# Android Compose remember not work if OutlinedTextField not focus

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, lifecycle

I tried to make a demo with a name DropdownMenu and a OutlinedTextField(Material 3) in a ViewPager. And I found that the `remember` of the `selectedIndex` not work if OutlinedTextField is not focused, since I change the `remember` to `rememberSaveable` everything works fine, any idea about why the focus of OutlinedTextField affect this ?

Compose code below

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Login() {

    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }

    var pwd by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp, Alignment.CenterVertically),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        UserMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onExpandChanged = { expanded = it },
            selectedIndex = selectedIndex,
            onIndexSelected = { selectedIndex = it },
        )

        OutlinedTextField(
            value = pwd,
            onValueChange = { pwd = it },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(.7f),
            label = { Text(text = "Password") },
            placeholder = { Text(text = "Password") },
            visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
            ),
        )

        Button(
            onClick = { showDialog = true },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(.7f),
            enabled = pwd.isNotBlank(),
        ) {
            Text(text = "Login")
        }
    }

    if (showDialog) {
        ErrorDialog(onDismiss = { showDialog = false })
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ErrorDialog(onDismiss: () -> Unit) {
    DialogContainer(onDismiss = onDismiss) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 28.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Password Error !!!",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 8.dp),
            )

            Button(
                onClick = onDismiss,
                modifier = Modifier.width(120.dp),
            ) {
                Text(text = "Close")
            }
        }
    }
}


private val users = listOf("James", "Eric", "Howard", "Jerry")

@Composable
private fun UserMenu(
    expanded: Boolean,
    onExpandChanged: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    selectedIndex: Int,
    onIndexSelected: (Int) -> Unit,
) {
    Box {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(.7f),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(text = "User : ")

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(PurpleGrey80)
                    .padding(vertical = 8.dp, horizontal = 16.dp)
                    .clickable(onClick = { onExpandChanged(true) }),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            ) {
                Text(text = users[selectedIndex])
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.round_arrow_down),
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
            }
        }
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { onExpandChanged(false) },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(.7f)
                .background(Pink80)
        ) {
            users.forEachIndexed { index, user ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = { Text(text = user) },
                    onClick = {
                        onIndexSelected(index)
                        onExpandChanged(false)
                    },
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```